# How to tar.gz everything but .jpg/gif/png/wmv/flv/tar.gz/zip?

Tags: unix, tar

how do I `tar.gz` everything apart from `jpg/gif/png/wmv/flv/zips`, recursively, via the Unix shell?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--exclude` option:

```
tar czvf myarchive.tar.gz --exclude=\*.{jpg,gif,png,wmv,flv,tar.gz,zip} rootdir
```

Comment: Just make sure you're running gnu tar, otherwise this flag won't exist.  On solaris you can specify an exclude file though.

Answer (score 2):

```
  find ./ -type f | egrep -v "\.(jpg|gif|png|wmv|flz|zips)$" | xargs tar -czf filename.tgz
```

Comment: you may have had a typo with "zips", so edit accordingly

Comment: Do you want to be a $ at the end there? Won't your egrep filter out jpg.txt?

Comment: tar (c)reate + xargs can be dangerous if your arg length is long enough that tar is called twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
find -type f -a ! \( \
                     -name '*.jpg' -o \
                     -name '*.gif' -o \
                     -name '*.png' -o \
                     -name '*.wmv' -o \
                     -name '*.flv' -o \
                     -name '*.tar.gz' -o \
                     -name '*.zip' \) \
 | xargs tar rvfz files.tgz
```

I used multilple lines to make it easier to edit later in case you made this into a shell script or shell function.

I use the -r flag for tar in case the number of files exceeds 1 call into xargs.  This way you can't exceed the argument buffer for tar.